# Chess-olition Derby

Tags: code-golf, random, chess, simulation

What could be more polar opposites than chess and [demolition derby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demolition_derby). You would think that no one who enjoys one would enjoy the other... until today.

## Rules

The starting position is a standard chess board:

```
RNBQKBNR
PPPPPPPP 





PPPPPPPP 
RNBQKBNR
```

Looks normal enough, until you find out it's an **EVERY PIECE FOR ITSELF, LAST PIECE STANDING** competition:

- On every turn, each piece on the board gets to make one randomly*-selected valid move (using it's standard move rules). However, the order the pieces move in is **randomized** every turn.
- A piece can capture **ANY PIECE**, even if it's the same color as it, even a king.
- Pawns can capture **FORWARD**, as well as diagonal. Moreover, like normal, if there is an empty space in front of it, a pawn can move two spaces on its first move (they can also capture that way.) Furthermore, pawns promote to any random piece (including king) other than a pawn.
- The winner is the last piece standing. However if after **1000 turns**, there is more than one piece left, all of the remaining pieces are winners.
- No En Passants, Checks, Castles, etc.

## Output

After every turn output the turn number, and what the board looks like. After a piece is killed it is removed from the board. After the first turn, the board may look like this:

```
1.
   K    
RBQ N BR  
NP  P P
  PP P P
R PP
BPN PNP
    K  R 
       Q
```

After 1000 moves the board may look like this:

```
1000.
  Q  K


P  N R

 R  B N   

  Q
```

And the game ends.

Or Maybe after 556 turns the board look like this:

```
556.


     R
```

So the game ends there.

*Please ensure all randomization done in this challenge is uniform (every possibility has an equal chance of occurring).

Comment: If a pawn can capture without moving diagonally, can it also move diagonally without capturing?

Comment: @tri no, it cant.

Comment: Can a pawn capture two pieces at once when it does a double move?

Comment: @orlp No, i should clarify that. You can only move two, if there's an empty space in front of you.

Comment: If a piece cannot move when it takes its turn, is it skipped? What about if it's skipped, then a move opens up due to the piece that moved after it? Can it move before the turn is over?

Comment: Also, in your examples, you need to distinguish the pawns as black or white (`p` black and `P` white is standard in [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation)), because they move different directions.

Comment: I think you should use 3 rounds as an example, not just randomized boards.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>862</s> <s>846</s> 844 bytes

```python
from random import*
A=-1;a,b=[(0,1),(0,A),(A,0),(1,0)],[(A,A),(A,1),(1,A),(1,1)]
r=range(8)
C='RNBQK';q=C+'BNR'
def m(x,y,B,t):
 P=B[y][x];M=[]
 for w,z in dict(zip('pP'+C,[[],[],a,zip([A,1,-2,2]*2,[2,2,1,1,-2,-2,A,A]),b]+[a+b]*2))[P]:
	for i in r[1:]:
	 X,Y=x+z*i,y+w*i;M+=(X,Y),
	 if P in'NK'or 1-(8>X>A<Y<8)or' '<B[Y][X]:break
 if P in'pP':d=[A,1][P<'p'];M=zip((x-1,x,x+1)[B[y+d][x-1]<'!':2+(B[y+d][-~x%8]>' ')],(y+d,)*3)+[(x,y+2*d)]*(t*B[y+d][x]<'!')
 return choice([(X,Y)for X,Y in M if-1<X<8>Y>A])
B=map(list,[q,'P'*8]+[' '*8]*4+['p'*8,q])
t=0
while t<1e3:
 t+=1;p=[(x,y)for y in r for x in r if' '<B[y][x]];shuffle(p)
 if len(p)<2:break
 while p:x,y=p.pop();Z=X,Y=m(x,y,B,t<2);B[Y][X],B[y][x]=B[y][x],' ';Z in p and p.remove(Z)
 for j in 0,7:
	for i in r:
	 if B[j][i]in'pP':B[j][i]=choice(C)
 print t
 for l in B:print''.join(l).upper()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLfb9owEH5e/grvYbKdXBBOJw0lMRLhsWrF@gRYfoCSDDNIXDddAw/719k5oZUmWXfnz75f3509t/umTq7XyjUn4jb1DpU52ca1YTCTscg2sJWKjUFwQDlDOYMxSoFSg8LbgIkem/VScB04idF@lWzCg7mkT4/Fz3uavch5RIvHJxrsyoqcWAdnKKDlaUAWslBnrTqdPUilA1I1jrzDhZia7Mxzyy7GMmoXNJqDUphYwwY8pjA1xAkkOkxAocZrD@DB2jSHrY7UJtriO@dqodPgi49tfGSnROoBsoSV7KJLaOAcvYcme4gkQ4wDvpmKLPAzfbyn6CdiNpkup7N8lU944yiheaFWWi11unXl5nfw@R@LTXfS16fVIqeW@tZ8yayLBXTQRYIrbDraYdux0Dn9StMkYjco/tt9m@gpJkCeGULAwzseKU9alIQ7rkPWhh/@vTcPiCvbN1eT531jnkum@iZ8u6h9ww9YXSzyZT6ZrqZITlDI08ayo3ltQb0AXdBwgnRhUtThd7QsWvCCP1s5Dt735liSNhflHY6sjaTIrOwr6pOce0770XWDaaqBoH6yOnvdv1XVsWSW9zQdyxrNPPlgbghvU4wn7cg2lvFsLf1sPlclT3h24xtuYT8WBzBVtvZ5LcFFJnbkylPzp2RrPqzTwb@N4cd/G5AOEy7UQSujb2O73eSNxjkGsM7ULWmHSEfvWqQ9Runo0JiaHfnozdrSMX69/gM)

Saved 18 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech

Comment: [855 bytes](https://goo.gl/4sdnWV) (not fully tested).

Comment: [847 bytes](https://goo.gl/En51VX).

Comment: I think `...]+[(a+b)]*2` can be either `...]+[a+b]*2` or `...,a+b,a+b]`.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 1849 bytes

```
<?$z=[R,N,B,Q,K,B,N,R];$y=[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_];$u=shuffle;$b=[$z,[P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P],$y,$y,$y,$y,[p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p],$z];$z=[R,N,B,Q,K];for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)for($j=0;$j<8;$j++)$r[]=[$i,$j];for(;$c++<=999;){for($i=$_=0;$i<8;$i++)for($j=0;$j<8;$j++)if($b[$i][$j]!=_)++$_;if($_<2)break;$u($r);$n=[];foreach($r as$l){list($y,$x)=$l;$a=$y+1;$d=$y-1;$j=$x+1;$t=$x-1;$p=$b[$y][$x];if($n[$y][$x]!=1&&$p!=_){$v=$e=$f=$g=$h=$k=$o=$q=$s=[];if($p==R||$p==K||$p==Q){$m=($p==K)?2:9;for($i=1;$i<$m;$i++){if(!$e&&$y-$i>=0){$v[]=[$y-$i,$x];if($b[$y-$i][$x]!=_)$e=1;}if(!$f&&$y+$i<8){$v[]=[$y+$i,$x];if($b[$y+$i][$x]!=_)$f=1;}if(!$g&&$x-$i>=0){$v[]=[$y,$x-$i];if($b[$y][$x-$i]!=_)$g=1;}if(!$h&&$x+$i<8){$v[]=[$y,$x+$i];if($b[$y][$x+$i]!=_)$h=1;}}}if($p==B||$p==K||$p==Q){$m=($p==K)?2:9;for($i=1;$i<$m;$i++){if(!$k&&$y-$i>=0&&$x-$i>=0){$v[]=[$y-$i,$x-$i];if($b[$y-$i][$x-$i]!=_)$k=1;}if(!$o&&$y-$i>=0&&$x+$i<8){$v[]=[$y-$i,$x+$i];if($b[$y-$i][$x+$i]!=_)$o=1;}if(!$q&&$y+$i<8&&$x-$i>=0){$v[]=[$y+$i,$x-$i];if($b[$y+$i][$x-$i]!=_)$q=1;}if(!$s&&$y+$i<8&&$x+$i<8){$v[]=[$y+$i,$x+$i];if($b[$y+$i][$x+$i]!=_)$s=1;}}}if($p==N){if($y-2>=0&&$t>=0)$v[]=[$y-2,$t];if($y-2>=0&&$j<8)$v[]=[$y-2,$j];if($d>=0&&$x-2>=0)$v[]=[$d,$x-2];if($d>=0&&$x+2<8)$v[]=[$d,$x+2];if($a<8&&$x-2>=0)$v[]=[$a,$x-2];if($a<8&&$x+2<8)$v[]=[$a,$x+2];if($y+2<8&&$t>=0)$v[]=[$y+2,$t];if($y+2<8&&$j<8)$v[]=[$y+2,$j];}if($p==P){if($y==1&&$b[$a][$x]==_)$v[]=[$y+2,$x];if($j<8&&$b[$a][$j]!=_)$v[]=[$a,$j];if($t>=0&&$b[$a][$t]!=_)$v[]=[$a,$t];$v[]=[$a,$x];}if($p==p){if($y==6&&$b[$d][$x]==_)$v[]=[$y-2,$x];if($j<8&&$b[$d][$j]!=_)$v[]=[$d,$j];if($t>=0&&$b[$d][$t]!=_)$v[]=[$d,$t];$v[]=[$d,$x];}$u($v);$v=$v[0];$b[$y][$x]=_;$w=$p;if($w==P&&$v[0]>6&&$u($z)&&$w=$z[0]);if($w==p&&$v[0]<1&&$u($z)&&$w=$z[0]);$b[$v[0]][$v[1]]=$w;$n[$v[0]][$v[1]]=1;}}echo $c.".
";foreach($b as$a)echo str_replace([_,p],[' ',P],join("",$a))."
";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVVdT6NQEH3fX6HNREvurbE8bLZLRxNfTYz6SgihBQRaCxbUfti/vt2ZeylfkmyyoeHmzsw5c@ZQLlmUHY/TW9ih/Swf5J18kvd0f5DPjgVbtF3Zuij4jnn0HobLwIIZ2rCT9qNsXY6Ebf2zM9m6KLsjlmY/xwrT9RBivLYgnv6imxCGCiUcSjiUUAjWtkMdYwmJhlgwF2KKk8nEMvYlB7j/oonDIcyIxrGJ5xxdQwhwLY66U9OYrQNvQVMOYW1YsEJbtQq8eUSRMy@HpbFfxnkx5PE2BsLSAg9hK8YW@LSOaE0QNrwvaOV9htxwSw03jmq0Ou3OcXxxARmr2MMHQoAQIrwgRAgLhBThDSFnEQzLEJ@/vni518sToV5RJe6NW/P35OTkmC2AV@3BnrDnEFCj7QjiG7zmXspK3suTqJnel7pcg8SMrYPChowV7GoNFR2oaELDCvpC0E23rVShGstADijsS4WNGNtpK1WkDRUnaMTQw6H06u6/vVrUXvXJ1661JiiNq4ZYVEOkba7OOJpK9FBVQ6UV1Vv1GPpUie@qREfVW0WVt6h6H63oYapE5S2nH5RvJN3UUxYsrBrRlFBopqqAXsZWPtF5/2S42SDweSqzXSDMmoDzosx7pTVNvNfAl/km3GvAt5zo6hcN/WW@KV9o@ScrHksrUL3ZZJ2n3gpk0xqI8sVJFF1ZpU@jWlZpSqFnLouKThEpawxS68gqHT812P@mY9Sjw@/q8Ht0@F0dflOHr3XwEfpBRyidah/2NWWrIxBdCz4RMsX6SZYRK5fcsFJC7QxaqWBHMeNUlJVF03FfEZNz1uFl7DgInxafsq0Y/2ODeZSewfxqcPVjUB/sMz7YPUMl82LtroNs6c2DIX3@6INlX55d8mctSePVcDCQVGlcDQh/OB7/pFkRp6v8OFr9BQ)

It can *definitely* be golfed more, and it looks somewhat like the workings of a madman (which, I suppose, it may be).

I am impressed at how fast random moves can clear the board (I've seen 15 moves do it). Also, I think the only one I saw hit the 1000 limit was two bishops on different colors dancing.